# D3 path tween changes side

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to do a path tween like this one: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621

Problem: The path is changing the side. The gray path is changing from left to right and the white path is changing from bottom to top. This isn't the expected transition!

Edit: My expected transition should be a simple grow transition. So the small one should grow to the bigger one.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wdv3rufs/

```
const PATHS = {
  FULL: {
    GRAY: 'M1035,429l-4.6-73.7L1092,223l-66,1l-66.3-36.4l-102.5,67.6L623.8,0L467.4,302.1l-218.7-82.9L77.6,317.4L0,214.5V429H1035z',
    WHITE: 'M0,429V292l249.4-72.9l135.4,56.6L623.8,0L824,232.5l135.7-44.9l26.7,190.5l29.3,16.8l19.3,34H0z'
  },
  SMALL: {
    GRAY: 'M0,429h834l-134.2-34.6l-37,23.2l-130.6-35.2l-112.7,33.5l-144.2-67l-96.7,65.2L43.5,377.5L0,391.4V429z',
    WHITE: 'M0,429h834l-134.2-34.6l-83.5,29l-84.1-41l-126.9,31.2l-130-64.7l-144.8,58.6l-87-30L0,386.1V429z'
  }
};

const pathTween = (d1, precision) => {
  return function() {
    const path0 = this;
    const path1 = path0.cloneNode();
    const n0 = path0.getTotalLength();
    const n1 = (path1.setAttribute('d', d1), path1).getTotalLength();

    const distances = [0];
    const dt = precision / Math.max(n0, n1);
    let i = 0;

    while ((i += dt) < 1) distances.push(i);
    distances.push(1);

    const points = distances.map(t => {
      const p0 = path0.getPointAtLength(t * n0);
      const p1 = path1.getPointAtLength(t * n1);

      return d3.interpolate([p0.x, p0.y], [p1.x, p1.y]);
    });

    return t => {
      return t < 1 ? 'M' + points.map(p => p(t)).join('L') : d1;
    };
  };
};

 const pathTransition = (path, d1) => {
    path.transition()
      .duration(10000)
      .attrTween('d', pathTween(d1, 4));
  }

var svg = d3.select('svg');

svg.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'white-mountain')
      .attr('d', PATHS.SMALL.WHITE)
      .call(pathTransition, PATHS.FULL.WHITE);

svg.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'gray-mountain')
      .attr('d', PATHS.SMALL.GRAY)
      .call(pathTransition, PATHS.FULL.GRAY);
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Can you add a note to your question describing the expected transition?

Comment: you don't seem to have bound the path data to the selections, here you need to use the selection.datum() method

Comment: @henry added my expected transition

Comment: @danimal the example doesnt do that either! Do i really need this? I mean there is an transition from one to the other, but there is somewhere a mistake.